# IsBitSet? function returns wrong result only when written as a Oneliner

Tags: c++

I am pretty stumped regarding the behavior of a function that tests if a certain bit is set in a unsigned int (16 bit) value.

I am testing the number: 57393 (1110 0000 0011 0001)

The non-working function is

```
bool IsBitSet(int bit, unsigned int value)
{
    return (((unsigned int)1) << bit) & value > 0;
}
```

Testing the function for `bit = 0; bit < 7; bit++` I get the results: `1 0 0 0 0 0` which is clearly not correct.

I then rewrote the function into individual steps:

```
bool IsBitSet(int bit, unsigned int value)
{
    unsigned int test = ((unsigned int)1) << bit;
    test = test & value;
    if (test > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my opinion this should do exactly the same. However now I get the correct output: `1 0 0 0 1 1`.

Given little experience with C++ I can't figure out what the difference between the two functions is. I am fine with keeping the longer function, but I want to understand where I went wrong in order not to run into this again.

The code is compiled for the Arduino platform, which may be important due to word length or compiler behavior.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `(unsigned int)1` can be written as `1u`.

Comment: Do you have warnings enabled? With GCC I got `warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '&'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I found the answer. I ran into a problem with operator precedence.
When doing

```
(((unsigned int)1) << bit) & value > 0
```

the greater than operator `>` takes precedence over the bitwise-and operator `&`, so `value > 0` is first evaluated to bool true which is implicitly cast to 1.

Then `(((unsigned int)1) << bit) & 1` is evaluated, giving `1` if `bit=0`, or `0` in other cases. This value is then again implicitly cast to bool for the return.

So the problem was failure to regard operator precedence combined with implicit casts without warning. Running the function step by step there is no problem with the precedence, since the comparison is always done after the bitwise-and.

The Oneliner can be fixed using additional brackets:

```
return ((((unsigned int)1) << bit) & value) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Although your self-answer is correct, you can gain a lot of readability by removing unnecessary brackets:
`return ((((unsigned int)1) << bit) & value) > 0;` is equivalent to:
`return (1U << bit) & value;`